# Windows Phone inherited application page: designer error but compiles

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a XAML Page which inherits from a userdefined class of mine:

```
<xpap:GenericListPage 
x:Class="my.View.ListPage"
xmlns:xpap="clr-namespace:my.View.Generic" ... />
```

Initially I wanted to use a generic base class for my XAML page, but that was no possible (at least in WP7; **is it possible in WP8 to use generic base classes for pages?**). So I ended up with this work-around (ExtendedPhoneApplicationPage inherits from PhoneApplicationPage adds extra functionality/behaviour that all my pages like ListPage etc. should have in commen):

```
namespace my.View
{
    namespace Generic
    {
        public partial class GenericListPage : 
            ExtendedPhoneApplicationPage<ListViewModel>
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public partial class ListPage : Generic.GenericListPage
    {
        ...
    }

    public class ExtendedPhoneApplicationPage<T> : 
        PhoneApplicationPage where T : class, IViewModelBase
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This worked fine all together until I installed the WP8 SDK (as far as I can remember). The designer says "invalid markup" and there is an error saying: "The name "GenericListPage" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:my.View.Generic"."

The strange part is, that the solution compiles and can be deployed on the emulator. Anyone know why or how to eliminate the error?

Comment: This is probably due to the differences in the XAML parsers in Visual Studio and on the actual device. Do you have a full repro? (that includes `ExtendedPhoneApplicationPage`)

Comment: @MattLacey: added deklaration of `ExtendedPhoneApplicationPage`